# Executable Text File set to execute

Tags: files, gedit, executable

So I downloaded AutoMouseClick because I need the software.

I downloaded the zip file, extracted it and made sure that under my Preferences settings in File are set to "Ask Each Time" whenever I click on it.

I made sure that the gedit file is executable as well under the Properties/Behavior tab.

My problem is that when I select "Run" nothing happens. Is it something I'm doing?

Comment: This sounds more like a statement than a question

Comment: Fixed. Apologies.

Comment: The top search result from duckduckgo is by murgee. It is listed as a windows only program. It might be able to run via wine. It seems pointless to pay for non native software when xdotool will work just fine.

Comment: @J.Starnes, You can expand your comment into an answer describing with some example how to use xdotool.

Comment: There's a link halfway down the page for Linux 64 bit version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`error while loading shared libraries: libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

The error above shows that `AutoMouseClick` did not ship with the required library. This is not your fault.

While `xdotool` doesn't have a nice gui, it is very flexible an powerful. Be aware that it will only work under `X` and not `wayland`. If you are willing to dig a little bit `xdotool` should far surpass `AutoMouseClick` for your needs.

If you would open a terminal and run `man xdotool`. You can read about using xdotool to send any valid keystroke or mouse action to the selected window. The following are a few of the examples from xdotool's man page.

Example: Send ctrl+c to all windows matching title "gdb"

```
xdotool search --name gdb key ctrl+c
```

Example: to type 'Hello world!' you would do:

```
xdotool type 'Hello world!'
```

Activate firefox and do a web search in a new tab for text in your clipboard

```
xdotool behave_screen_edge --delay 1000 top-left \
   search --classname Navigator \
   windowactivate --sync key --delay 250 ctrl+t ctrl+k ctrl+v Return
```

Emulate focus-follows-mouse

```
xdotool search . behave %@ mouse-enter windowfocus
```